# What does "selbst" mean?

Tags: meaning

So I more or less understand that it means "self", however I still don't get how to translate it. For example in the sentence:

> Ganz ehrlich, ich wusste zu Beginn selbst nicht, ob ich die Beantwortung der Frage für wichtig halte.

I guess "self not" is not a proper translation of "selbst nicht".

So are there other usage of "selbst"?

Comment: Vogel, you were right, the word order confused me. So does "selbst" usually stay near the end of a sentence?

Comment: Not really. The fun thing about the placement of selbst is, that it shifts the meaning of the whole sentence.. I think this is worth a new question.

Comment: Aaaaaand there it is: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/bedeutungsverschiebung-bei-umstellung-von-satz-mit-selbst

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making a small erroneous assumption here. *"selbst"* here is primarily connected to *"ich"* in this sentence.

*"nicht"* is connected to the verb (*"wissen"*) here.

One could reformulate:

> Ich selbst wusste nicht [...]

Then the translation gets clear:

> ich selbst --> I self --> I myself

And then translating the whole sentence gives us:

> Honestly in the beginning I myself didn't know, whether I believed the question's answering to be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

It translates roughly to either "even" or "my-, your-, his-, one-, herself"/"our-, theirselves".

> In all honesty, I **myself** didn't initially know whether I regarded the answer to the question as important.
>
> In all honesty, I didn't **even** initially know whether I regarded the answer to the question as important.

You can also use "selbst" to emphasize that something was done by you

> Das habe ich selbst gemacht! == I did that by myself!
>
> Die Königin selbst könnte das nicht machen == The queen herself couldn't do that

Comment: While *"even"* here fits the meaning behind the usage of *"selbst"* wonderfully, I wouldn't call it an actual translation, ---not even roughly--- nicht selbst ungefähr 

Comment: @Vogel612 selbst nicht ungefähr