# Bedeutungsverschiebung bei Umstellung von Satz mit "selbst"?

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

Man vergleiche Folgendes:

> Ich wusste am Ende selbst nicht...

mit

> Ich wusste selbst am Ende nicht...

Wie erklärt sich die Bedeutungsverschiebung vom *"Ich"* auf den *"Zeitpunkt des Endes"*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es geht hier weniger um eine Bedeutungsverschiebung sondern darum, dass es sich um zwei gleichlautende, aber verschiedene Wörter handelt.

Im ersten Satz handelt es sich um das Demonstrativpronomen **selbst**, das sich auf den Sprecher bezieht.

Im zweiten Satz handelt es sich um das Adverb<sup>Duden</sup> bzw. die "Fokuspartikel"<sup>[canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Partikel/Fokuspartikel.html)</sup> **selbst**, mit der die Zeitangabe "am Ende" näher bestimmt/qualifiziert wird.

Gleiche Buchstabenfolge, zwei verschiedene Wörter mit verschiedener Bedeutung und verschiedener Funktion.

Comment: Dann könnte man auch noch betrachten: Selbst ich wusste...

Comment: @CarstenSchultz das fällt dann aber wohl in die Kategorie "Fokuspartikel"

Comment: @Vogel612, ja, und die Stellung bestimmt, worauf er sich bezieht.

Comment: Laut Wiktionary ist "selbst" ein Demonstrativpronomen. Ich glaube das steht auch in der Duden-Grammatik so, aber ich finde die Stelle nicht.